# Get the last value in comma separated string

Tags: php

I have this string: `24.045,25.531,26.890` as php variable `$numbers`

How can i echo the number after the last comma (in this case 26.890)? The number can vary in size, e.g. `9.04` or `120.34521`. So I need to set the last comma as my starting point.

Can I search for the last comma, and echo whatever that is behind it?

Comment: `$ar = explode(',', $str); $res = $ar[count($ar)-1];`

Comment: Read about the PHP function [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). It solves your problem easily. To find the last comma, read about [`strrchr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the numbers into an array and [`end`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) to get the last item of the array:

```
$numbers = '24.045,25.531,26.890';
$numbers = explode(',', $numbers);
$lastNumber = end($numbers);
```

**demo:** https://ideone.com/VDppCP

Comment: *Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference*

Answer (score 5):

Without creating a temporary array with all of the numbers (which you might not need):

```
echo substr($numbers, strrpos($numbers, ',') + 1);
```

And if you need to handle strings that might not contain a comma at all:

```
echo substr(
    $numbers,
    ($lastCommaPos = strrpos($numbers, ',')) !== false ? $lastCommaPos + 1 : 0
);
```

Comment: Note that if the comma-separated list contains only 1 item (i.e. no comma) then this version will return the original string with the first character dropped (strrpos will return FALSE which evaluates to 0).